# how to make the program wait until I move the chessboard

Tags: c++, opencv, camera-calibration

I want to calibrate my stereo camera so, I am trying to capture 10 images for a chessboard from the right and the left camera .

what the code should do:
capture 10 images  of a chessboard from the right and the left camera.The program saves the two images if both contain a clear corner points. The program should wait 20 frames for me to change the position of the chessboard.

what is happening :
it capture the 10 good images and saves them but, it does not wait for me to change the position of the chessboard

this is my code:

```
int captureImages_stereoCal()
{
    CvCapture* captureL = cvCreateCameraCapture(1);
    assert(captureL);
    waitKey(10000);
    CvCapture* captureR = cvCreateCameraCapture(2);
    assert(captureR);
    waitKey(10000);
    /*Mat imageL ;
    Mat imageR*/ ;
    int nx=8 , nh=5;


    int frame=0;
    int s =1;
    int ss;

    CvPoint2D32f* cornersL = new CvPoint2D32f[nx*nh];
    int corner_countL;
    CvPoint2D32f* cornersR = new CvPoint2D32f[nx*nh];
    int corner_countR;

    IplImage *imageL=cvQueryFrame(captureL);
    IplImage *gray_imageL=cvCreateImage(cvGetSize(imageL),8,1);
    IplImage *CimageL=cvCreateImage(cvGetSize(imageL),32,3);
    IplImage *imageR=cvQueryFrame(captureR);
    IplImage *gray_imageR=cvCreateImage(cvGetSize(imageR),8,1);
    IplImage *CimageR=cvCreateImage(cvGetSize(imageL),32,3);
    const int board_dt=20;

    while(s<=12)
    {
        if(frame++ % board_dt == 0)
        {
            string Result;     
            ostringstream convert;  
            ss=s-2;
            convert << ss; 
            Result = convert.str(); 

            //n=(char)s;
            //waitKey(1000);
            //Left -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
            string nameL="L.jpg";

            //Find chessboard corners:
            int foundL = cvFindChessboardCorners(imageL, Size(nx,nh), cornersL, &corner_countL,CV_CALIB_CB_ADAPTIVE_THRESH | CV_CALIB_CB_FILTER_QUADS);
            //Get Subpixel accuracy on those corners
            cvCvtColor(imageL, gray_imageL, CV_BGR2GRAY);
            cvFindCornerSubPix(gray_imageL, cornersL, corner_countL,cvSize(11,11),cvSize(-1,-1), cvTermCriteria(CV_TERMCRIT_EPS+CV_TERMCRIT_ITER, 30, 0.1 ));
            //Draw it
            Mat MimageL(imageL);
            CimageL=imageL;
            cvDrawChessboardCorners(CimageL, Size(nx,nh), cornersL,corner_countL, foundL);

            //Right -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
            string nameR="R.jpg";

            //Find chessboard corners:
            int foundR = cvFindChessboardCorners(imageR, Size(nx,nh), cornersR, &corner_countR,CV_CALIB_CB_ADAPTIVE_THRESH | CV_CALIB_CB_FILTER_QUADS);
            //Get Subpixel accuracy on those corners
            cvCvtColor(imageR, gray_imageR, CV_BGR2GRAY);
            cvFindCornerSubPix(gray_imageR, cornersR, corner_countR,cvSize(11,11),cvSize(-1,-1), cvTermCriteria(CV_TERMCRIT_EPS+CV_TERMCRIT_ITER, 30, 0.1 ));
            //Draw it
            Mat MimageR(imageR);
            CimageR=imageR;
            cvDrawChessboardCorners(CimageR, Size(nx,nh), cornersR,corner_countR, foundR);
            cvShowImage( "CalibrationL", CimageL );
            cvShowImage( "CalibrationR", CimageR );



            if(s>2)
            {   
                if((corner_countL==(nx*nh)) && (corner_countR==(nx*nh)) )
                {
                    nameL.insert(1,Result);

                    imwrite(nameL,MimageL); 
                    nameR.insert(1,Result);

                    imwrite(nameR,MimageR);
                    s++;
                }
            }
            int c = cvWaitKey(15);
            if(c == 'p')
            {
                c = 0;
                while(c != 'p' && c != 27)
                {
                    c = cvWaitKey(250);
                }
            }
            if(c == 27)
                return 0;
            imageL = cvQueryFrame(captureL);

            imageR = cvQueryFrame(captureR);
            if(s<3)
                s++;
        }// frame++ end

    } // while end
    return 0;
}
```

Also , after it draws the corners it saves the image with the corners drawn on it. I want to save the images with out any changes.

Comment: A physical chessboard?

Comment: 2005 called, they want their IplImage back...

Comment: yes , a physical chessboard
9 x 6 squares ... each square is 3 x 3 cm

Comment: So the if-statement should be entered after 20 frames?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the problem correctly, it's because you're using a post-increment on your if-statement conditional:

`if(frame++ % board_dt == 0)`

You initialize `frame` to be 0 above, so on the 1st call, the if-statement is effectively testing `(0 % 20) == 0`, which is true.

You can change the if-statement to be a pre-increment, e.g. 
`if(++frame % board_dt == 0)` to get the behavior you are looking for